# Query beamer document class option aspectratio in a .sty file

Tags: beamer, document-classes, options, kvoptions, styles

I am writing my own latex beamer style. I want to use different background graphics depending on the aspect ratio chosen in the documentclass in the main file, like
`\documentclass[12pt, aspectratio=169]{beamer}`

So how can I access the value of aspectratio in my .sty file?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One way could be to use the `\ifdimcomp{⟨dimen expression⟩}{⟨relation⟩}{⟨dimen expression⟩}{⟨true⟩}{⟨false⟩}` macro to test for different paperwidths (and height in case of `169` and `1610`):

```
\documentclass[
    aspectratio=169
%   aspectratio=43
    ]{beamer}
    
\begin{document}

\makeatletter
\ifdimcomp{\beamer@paperwidth}{=}{12.80cm}{43}{}
\ifdimcomp{\beamer@paperwidth}{=}{14.85cm}{141}{}
\ifdimcomp{\beamer@paperwidth}{=}{13.50cm}{32}{}
\ifdimcomp{\beamer@paperwidth}{=}{12.50cm}{54}{}
\ifdimcomp{\beamer@paperwidth}{=}{14.00cm}{149}{}
\ifdimcomp{\beamer@paperwidth}{=}{16.00cm}{
    \ifdimcomp{\beamer@paperheight}{=}{10.00cm}{1610}{}
    \ifdimcomp{\beamer@paperheight}{=}{9.00cm}{169}{}
}{}
\makeatother

\end{document}
```

---

With the [current beamer development version](https://github.com/josephwright/beamer/commit/33672c652c12d7880360ddaa6f7d948285e609d0) (which should be included in beamer v3.70 or newer), one can now simply use the `\insertaspectratio` macro:

```
\documentclass[
    aspectratio=169
%   aspectratio=43
    ]{beamer}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\insertaspectratio
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Great, works like a charm!

Comment: @Philippp Good to hear!